# Filenames getting appended every time I search and store them in list using Google Drive API?

Tags: python, django, google-drive-api

I am using the google drive API to search inside of a folder named 'Users' and then I store the filenames the reside in that folder in a list. In Django every time I refresh a page which triggers this google API function the list of filename gets appended.
Ex. 1st execution

```
files_in_users = ['1','2','3','4','5']
```

same page refreshed again

```
files_in_users = ['1','2','3','4','5','1','2','3','4','5']
```

And this goes on every time I refresh the page. I have even tried to restart the server but there is always some redundant data in the list. I have also used the `list.clear()` function at the end of execution. Why does this happen? Is there some cache that I need to delete after each execution?

Code:

```
#GET ID OF USER FOLDER FROM DRIVE
drive_users_id = get_user_file_id(service)
    
# GET THE FILES IN USER FOLDER FROM DRIVE
flow_of_users_file = service.files().list(q=" '{0}' in parents ".format(drive_users_id),spaces ='drive').execute()
for i in flow_of_users_file['files']:
    files_in_user_folder.append(i['name'])
    print('files in drive are :', files_in_user_folder)
```

After printing the `flow_of_users_file` which is of type Dictionary, I could see there are redundant data in it, some files are getting appended every time I execute that line

## VIEWS.PY

```
def datapage(request):
    #all_data = Userdata.objects.all()
    files_in_user_folder = []
    #DRIVE API SETTINGS
    creds = None
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)
    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    #GET ID OF USER FOLDER FROM DRIVE
    drive_users_id = get_user_file_id(service)

    # GET THE FILES IN USER FOLDER FROM 
    flow_of_users_file = service.files().list(q=" '{0}' in parents ".format(drive_users_id),spaces ='drive').execute()
    print(type(flow_of_users_file))
    for i in flow_of_users_file['files']:
        files_in_user_folder.append(i['name'])
    # FILES IN LOCAL FOLDER CALLED 'user_output_files'
    files_in_local_folder = os.listdir(settings.BASE_DIR+'/users_output_files/')
    print('files in drive are :', files_in_user_folder)
    print('files in local folder are :',files_in_local_folder)

    #CHECK IF ANY FILE UPDATES EXIST
    z = list(set(files_in_user_folder)-set(files_in_local_folder))

    #Checking if the local files have been generated
    if len(files_in_local_folder) == 0:
        print("No local files exist creating everything")
        for folder in flow_of_users_file['files']:
            name_of_folder = folder['name']
            if not os.path.exists(settings.BASE_DIR+'/users_output_files/'+str(name_of_folder)):
                print('No file does not exist')
                os.mkdir(settings.BASE_DIR+'/users_output_files/'+str(name_of_folder))
            folder_mime_type = folder['mimeType']
            if folder_mime_type == 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder':
                flow_of_file = service.files().list(q=" '{0}' in parents ".format(folder['id']),spaces ='drive').execute()
                for file in flow_of_file['files']:
                    print('The contents of folder {0} are {1}'.format(name_of_folder, file['name'] ))
                    response = service.files().get_media(fileId = file['id']).execute()
                    print(type(response))
                    data = json.loads(response)
                    converter_xls(name_of_folder, file['name'],data )
```

Comment: Can you post the full view function? The snippet you currently posted does not define the `files_in_user_folder` variable for example.

Comment: `files_in_user_folder` is just an list which is initialised as `files_in_user_folder = [] `

Comment: It is very important to know *where* this variable is initialized. If it's a the `module` level then mutations to this list will persist during the lifetime of this application, which would explain the behaviour you a seeing.

Comment: Please try and provide us with a minimum of data to reproduce your problem. Can you show us the view from your views.py where this function is being mapped to?
Take care to REMOVE any sensitive data. And also a copy of the Dictionary you are being returned in `flow_of_users_data`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if you aren't clearing `files_in_user_folder`, and then you're appending things to it.

You should try

```
# GET THE FILES IN USER FOLDER FROM DRIVE
flow_of_users_file = service.files().list(q=" '{0}' in parents ".format(drive_users_id),spaces ='drive').execute()
files_in_user_folder.clear()
for i in flow_of_users_file['files']:
    files_in_user_folder.append(i['name'])
print('files in drive are :', files_in_user_folder)
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried this but the problem seems to be in flow_of_users_file which is a dictionary type. whenever I print it I can see some redundant values. And if I try using flow_of_users.clear() it says "referenced before assignment"

Comment: `flow_of_users.clear()` is referenced before assignment or `files_in_user_folder.clear()` ??

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this redundancy was occurring was because of similar data in my drive Trash. So, while scanning for folders it was appending the trash data and my drive data.

Comment: I suspected so because you where not using the `trashed=False` parameter in the query. But had my doubts if a trashed file, retained the parent folder attribute. 
It makes sense it does so recovering the file is possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because you have deleted the files in your drive, and now they are in the  trash. Which means they still have the parent folder attribute pointing to `Users` folder; BUT now the attribute named `trashed` is set to `true`.

So if you want to avoid *duplicate filenames* take care to pass `trashed = false` in your query string.

Further reading:

- [Files list method](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/list)
- [files.list querying](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/search-files)
- [File resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files#resource-representations)